# Lombok: How to define a special method which runs upon the Object construction?

Tags: java, lombok, object-construction

I have a `@Value @AllArgsConstructor` class, and I want each instance of it to have an ID(The first object has the ID of 1, the second is 2, etc..).
until now, before I used lombok but a constructor, my solution used to be:
`private static int idsCounter = 0;` and then
`this.id = ++idsCounter;` inside the constructor.

so how am I supposed to implement this with Lombok which eliminates the constuctor?

Comment: ...bite the bullet and write your own constructor?

Comment: what if I have many fields? It'll be annoying to write the constructor myself(and use @Getter).. Are you sure that there's no feature to add some code(like a method) which would be applied to created Object?

Comment: as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41156010/is-there-any-postconstruct-feature-of-lombok and https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1207, it's not a thing

Comment: Annoying?  How long do you think it will take?  More than 15 minutes?

Comment: Readability? duh?

Comment: You can bypass the constructor and write something like :  `private int id = IDCounter.incrementAndGet();`

Answer (score 0):

Add an initialisation block:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
class MyClass {
    static int idsCounter = 0;
    private int id;
    // other fields
    
    {
        id = ++idsCounter;
    }
}
```

This block runs after the constructor.

It's not a perfect solution because you'll have to provide a value for `id`, but just provide `0` as it will be overridden by the code in the block.