# Default value on null with Lombok or Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok, boilerplate

I have some constructors like these where I must handle with parameters being `null`.

```
    public Element(int value1, String value2, String value3, String value4) {
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.value2 = value2 != null ? value2 : "";
        this.value3 = value3 != null ? value3 : "";
        this.value4 = value4 != null ? value4 : "";
    }
```

Yes I know, I could write a utility-method or my own annotation to reduce the boiler plate code for params 2,3,4

But is there any existing solution?
Something like `@DefaultOnNull("")` on the parameter or even the class?

Comment: Related, but not a satisfactory solution: [Default value in lombok. How to init default with both constructor and builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47883931/default-value-in-lombok-how-to-init-default-with-both-constructor-and-builder)

Comment: A potential helper method which exists in the jdk would be `java.util.Objects.requireNonNullElse(value2, "")`

Comment: If you wish to do the null check and setting `""` after the usual `this.x=x` initialization steps, then this is a kind of workaround for a similar problem - https://stackoverflow.com/a/67815143/7804477

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all comments.
I solved it this way to reduce the boiler plate code at least a little bit:

```
    public Element(int value1, String value2, String value3, String value4) {
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.value2 = Objects.requireNonNullElse(value2, "");
        this.value3 = Objects.requireNonNullElse(value3, "");
        this.value4 = Objects.requireNonNullElse(value4, "");
    }
```

Comment: How does this "reduce" boilerplate code? :-) This is same as the code in your question but done in a different way.

Comment: That's why I said "a little bit". I only have to write value2, value3, ... once and therefore this reduces the risk of copy & paste errors.

Comment: Yes. Maybe a method `getDefault(value){ return Objects.requireNonNullElse(value, ""); }` so that it may look a bit compact and also you need not pass `""` as well (if you want `""` as default in all cases)

Answer (score -1):

You can use below code

```
this.value2 = StringUtils.defaultString(value2);
```

StringUtils is an Apache commons library and is widely used and standard library for String related operations.
Maven - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.10

Comment: Thanks, but this a) requires an additional library and b) works only for `""` as default string.