# RequiredArgsConstructor with custom assignment

Tags: lombok

I'm curious if it's possible to assign a custom value during a constructor call using @RequiredArgsConstructor.  I.e.

```
private String value1;
private String value2;
private String value3;

public MyConstructor(String value1, String value2) {
    this.value1 = value1;
    this.value2 = value2;
    this.value3 = createString();
}
```

Instead I'll be looking for:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyConstructor {
    @NonNull
    private String value1;
    @NonNull
    private String value2;
    private String value3;

    private String createString() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Comment: This might help -> [Is there any "PostConstruct" feature of lombok?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67815143/7804477)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign `createString()` directly in the definition of the attribute. Therefore, when a new instance is created, also the `value3` is initialized.

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyConstructor {
    @NonNull
    private String value1;
    @NonNull
    private String value2;
    private String value3 = createString();

    private String createString() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this happen after the constructor?

Comment: Yes, when the object is created

Comment: Did my answer help you? or do you want me to add something to my answer? otherwise, feel free to accept my answer if you like.

Comment: Hey sorry for not getting back to you on this. Yeah this helped me, thanks for your answer.